# Trouble installing sleuthkit package

Tags: software-installation

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/ABC/Downloads/sleuthkit-4.1.3/bindings/java/build.xml:119: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ABC/Downloads/sleuthkit-4.1.3/bindings/java/build.xml:98: impossible to resolve dependencies:
    resolve failed - see output for details

Total time: 40 seconds
make[2]: *** [all-local] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ABC/Downloads/sleuthkit-4.1.3/bindings/java'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ABC/Downloads/sleuthkit-4.1.3/bindings/java'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
root@ubuntu:/home/ABC/Downloads/sleuthkit-4.1.3#
```

Comment: As it is currently, we can't really help you - the error says to see the output for details and I don't see any useful details in the output :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing the same problem as described [here](https://github.com/sleuthkit/sleuthkit/issues/345) which says there is some problem in the `bindings/java/ivysettings.xml` in locating the repositories for `sqlite-jdbc-3.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Currently it looks in `http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.0-SNAPSHOT/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

but the file Ivy wants is actually at

`https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.0-SNAPSHOT/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.0-20130827.035027-1.jar`